# CentOS useradd doesn't work in a while do loop - commad not found

Tags: while-loop, centos7

I'm trying to create a script for reading a file with user and password to create new users.

This is the script

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash
while read -r usr pwd; do
     /usr/sbin/useradd $usr
     echo $pwd | /usr/bin/passwd --stdin $usr
done < ./new_users
```

When I execute it I get the following messages:

```bash
./script_newusers: line 3:  : command not found
./script_newusers: line 4:    : command not found
passwd: Unknown user name 'user1'.
```

I'm using CentOS7.9

But if I execute the same commads in a script to create a new user they work fine

```bash
/usr/sbin/useradd user1
echo passord1  | /usr/bin/passwd --stdin user1
```

If I use the following loop in a script to read a file, it also works fine

```bash
while read -r usr pwd; do
     echo $usr
     echo $pwd
done < ./new_users
```

The same commands inside the loop in a script doesn't work and I don't understand why. Any idea on how can I fix it?
Thanks!